# Is there a way to import a react component without using 'import' statement

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm new to React. Just trying out things.

So far I have been using CDNs for React, React-DOM, and React-Bootstrap. I had no trouble using components of React-Bootstrap using the example code below:

```
var Alert = ReactBootstrap.Alert;
```

Now my problem is I want to use a component that is not provided by React-Bootstrap so I tried to look for components available in Github. I found a lot of the components that I am looking for but all of them are available for installation via *npm* which I am avoiding since I'm using React thru CDN. I know it is recommended to use *npm* or *create-react app*, but that's not how I started my application.

So is there a way to import components like how I did in React-Bootstrap components? For example:

```
var Select = React.Select; // import Select from 'react-select';
```

Comment: Unless those components are hosted somewhere (like React is with the CDN) then that won't be possible. And almost all packages aren't hosted anywhere, you're expected to install them with a package manager. Using react and stuff from a CDN is usually only done at the very, VERY start of learning React, just to get a feel of some super basic stuff. So it's never long before you move to a proper, package managed setup. If you don't wanna bother setting it up, look into `create-react-app` to set up a React repo where you can easily play around and add packages.

Comment: Did you read it? https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: @Jayce444 I know I should install react and other packages that I need, it's just I'm trying out things since I'm new and kinda want to understand the basics first and exploring before diving in and setting up everything. Appreciate the comment tho, thanks!